# Skip to the second page (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

There are three pages in my jquery mobile site, I want it to skip the left page so the second page will load first.

My fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/MMwWC/
(You can swipe/slide it with you mouse to navigate through pages)

I have my code here:

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="left" data-url="left" data-theme="a">LEFT PAGE</div>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-url="home" data-theme="a">HOME</div>
<div data-role="page" id="right" data-url="right" data-theme="a">RIGHT PAGE</div>
```

JS

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
            if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true, changeHash: false}, true, true);
            }
        });
        $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true, changeHash: false}, true, true);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: dimgray;
}

#home {
    background: dodgerblue;
}

#left {
    background: red;
}

#right {
    background: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery mobile shows the first page that is in the html file. You can just directly move the home page to top. Or It basically depends from where you are loading this page ,when change to this page by href property means you can do

```
<a href="foo.html#home">link</a>
```

this will make home page load first and rest can happen through your code or

```
$.mobile.changePage("foo.html#home");
```

this will do the same.